# Error converting data type varchar to bigint

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am retrieving values from listbox and formatting them in string as

```
if (lbRaisedByLogin.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        foreach (ListItem item in lbRaisedByLogin.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected == true)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("{0},", item.Value);
            }
        }

        searchCase.raisedByLogin = sb.ToString().TrimEnd(Convert.ToChar(","));
        sb.Length = 0;
    }
```

I am passing these strings to store procedure as parameter (Datatype-- Varchar(Max))

in stored procedure I am comparing these values like

```
SELECT * FROM AUS_CID_Cases
WHERE
AddedBy IN ( @raisedByLogin )
```

Where @raisedByLogin is one of the parameter i passed. It has values like @raisedByLogin="4,2,1"

AddedBy has datatype bigint.

When I run code I get error as "Error converting data type varchar to bigint.".. I understand it is because AddedBy column has datatype bigint. I can not change that datatype.

However when i cast AddedBy like

```
SELECT * FROM AUS_CID_Cases
WHERE
CAST(AddedBy as VARCHAR) IN ( @raisedByLogin )
```

I dont get error, but nothing is selected i.e I dont get any result from select statement.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create this view

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))       
as       
begin       
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return
```

then change the query to this and try,

```
SELECT * FROM AUS_CID_Cases
WHERE
CAST(AddedBy as VARCHAR) IN ( select * from split(@raisedByLogin,',') )
```

found above Function [here](http://blog.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx), and managed to solve this issue sometime back...

Answer (score 0):

try to build SQL select query inside stored procedure and execute after that.

```
DECLARE @raisedByLogin varchar(600)

SET @SQL = 
'SELECT * FROM AUS_CID_Cases
 WHERE
  AddedBy IN (' + @raisedByLogin + ')' 

EXEC(@SQL)
```

check [How to pass a list of values or array to SQL Server stored procedure?](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/passing_arrays_to_stored_procedures.htm) for more information